# Issue with DatetimeField and strftime

Tags: python, django, datetime, strftime

I would like to convert my DateTimeField :

```
download_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('download date'), null=True)
```

with `strftime`like this :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_download_temp = Download.objects.exclude(download_date=None).order_by('-download_date')[0]
print(f"Last download temp : {last_download_temp}")

last_download = last_download_temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(f"Last download : {last_download}")
```

It returns :

```
Last download temp : 2019-01-07 09:10:01.509484+00:00

File "/home/Bureau/Projets/Publication/publication/src/web/freepub/views/main.py" in get_context_data
  236.             last_download = last_download_temp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /freepub/stats
Exception Value: 'Download' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I don't find why it doesn't work ? 
Do I need to convert my `last_download_temp` before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using `Download` object, but it should `download_date` attribute of `Download` object. So you should do it like this:

```
last_download = last_download_temp.download_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Oh ok it's a mistake from me ! Thank you very much !